# I want write a function -fetch_cached() which will check in local

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

I want write a function -fetch_cached() which will check in local. Otherwise , download the link using axios get and save the results in local storage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please give us what code you have tried and read the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us better answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions. According to me this should run fine.

```
const fetch_cached = (url,key) => {

  axios.get(url).then(response => {

    let data = response.data;

    caches.has(key).then(bool => {

      if(false) {

        console.log(bool);

        console.log("The data is present in localcache.")

      } else {

        console.log("Data is being stored in localstorage")

        localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(data));

        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));

      }

    });
  }) .catch(error => {

      return error;
  });
}

fetch_cached(url,key);
```

Use your own URL and key within fetch_fetched() function.